# linq to sql remove URLS that starts with same domain

Tags: c#, .net, linq, visual-studio

I have a list of URLS in a data table. I want to remove rows that starts with same domain. Right now I have this code:

```
List<int> toRemove = new List<int>();
            toRemove.Clear();
            string initialDomain;
            string compareDomainName;
            for(int i = 0; i<UrlList.Rows.Count -1; i++)
            {
                if (toRemove.Contains(i))
                    continue;

                initialDomain = new Uri(UrlList.Rows[i][0] as String).Host;
                for(int j = i + 1; j < UrlList.Rows.Count; j++)
                {
                    compareDomainName = new Uri(UrlList.Rows[j][0] as String).Host;
                    if (String.Compare(initialDomain, compareDomainName, true) == 0)
                    {
                        toRemove.Add(j);
                    }
                }

                percent = i * 100 / total;
                if (percent > lastPercent)
                {
                    progress.EditValue = percent;
                    Application.DoEvents();
                    lastPercent = percent;

                }
            }

            for(int i = toRemove.Count-1; i>=0; i--)
            {
                UrlList.Rows.RemoveAt(toRemove[i]);
            }
```

It works well for small amount of data, but when I load a long list of URLs it is very slow. Now I want to move to linq, but I do not know how to realize this using linq. Any help?

Update ***
I do not need to remove eduplicate rows. For ex.
I have a list of URLS
Now, I know how to remove duplicate rows. My problem is: 
I have a simple list of urls:

```
http://centroid.steven.centricagency.com/forms/contact-us?page=1544
http://chirp.wildcenter.org/poll
http://itdiscover.com/links/
http://itdiscover.com/links/?page=132
http://itdiscover.com/links/?page=2
http://itdiscover.com/links/?page=3
http://itdiscover.com/links/?page=4
http://itdiscover.com/links/?page=6
http://itdiscover.com/links/?page=8

http://www.foreignpolicy.com/articles/2010/06/21/la_vie_en
http://www.foreignpolicy.com/articles/2010/06/21/the_worst_of_the_worst
http://www.foreignpolicy.com/articles/2011/04/25/think_again_dictators
http://www.foreignpolicy.com/articles/2011/08/22/the_dictators_survival_guide
http://www.gsioutdoors.com/activities/pdp/glacier_ss_nesting_wine_glass/gourmet_backpacking/
http://www.gsioutdoors.com/products/pdp/telescoping_foon_orange/
http://www.gsioutdoors.com/products/pdp/telescoping_spoon_blue/
```

now I want this list:

```
    http://centroid.steven.centricagency.com/forms/contact-us?page=1544
    http://chirp.wildcenter.org/poll
    http://itdiscover.com/links/
    http://www.foreignpolicy.com/articles/2010/06/21/la_vie_en
http://www.gsioutdoors.com/activities/pdp/glacier_ss_nesting_wine_glass/gourmet_backpacking/
```

Comment: So basically you want to remove duplicate rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result = urls.Distinct(new UrlComparer());
```

---

```
public class UrlComparer : IEqualityComparer<string>
{
    public bool Equals(string x, string y)
    {
        return new Uri(x).Host == new Uri(y).Host;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(string obj)
    {
        return new Uri(obj).Host.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

You can also implement an extension method `DistinctBy`

```
public static partial class MyExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> DistinctBy<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        HashSet<TKey> knownKeys = new HashSet<TKey>();
        return source.Where(x => knownKeys.Add(keySelector(x)));
    }
}
```

---

```
var result = urls.DistinctBy(url => new Uri(url).Host);
```

Comment: Thanks, I've used IEqualityComparer method. When will have time will try to compare speed for both examples.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
IEnumerable<string> DeleteDuplicates(IEnumerable<string> source)
{
    var  hosts = new HashSet<string>();

    foreach (var s in source)
    {
        var host = new Uri(s).Host.ToLower();

        if (hosts.Contains(host))   
            continue;

        hosts.Add(host);

        yield return s;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi implement this function to remove the duplicate rows

```
 public DataTable FilterURLS(DataTable urllist)
 {
      return
           (from urlrow in urllist.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
            group urlrow by urlrow.Field<string>("Host") into g
            select g
            .OrderBy(r => r.Field<int>("ID"))
            .First()).CopyToDataTable();
  }
```